# Asp.net url rewrite for image file extensions

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I'm replacing all the images in our website with .webp

Basically we had .jpeg images and now replaced with .webp images.
But we're seeing many images in google especially.
And to prevent 404 errors I'm trying to find a way to redirect to webp images.

We're using asp.net rewrite in web.config file.
But couldn't figure out what I'm missing.

sample old image link: https://www.example.com/SiteThumbs/g/google.com.jpeg
and the new image link: https://www.example.com/SiteThumbs/g/google.com.webp

Just the extension is different now.

And the rule in web.config file:

```
<rule name="Old Images" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^SiteThumbs/(.*).jpeg" ignoreCase="true" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="SiteThumbs/{R:1}.webp" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

Could anyone advice please.

Answer (score 0):

This rule is working actually.
It was Cloudflare caching the images so never hits the server.